# Xcode 4.1 custom DataFormatter bundle

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, debuggervisualizer

I'm trying to make a custom Data Formatter bundle to allow me to print things like STL containers more prettily, etc.

I've followed the instructions online as well as I can, however I can't seem to get any *bundle* code to run.  All I can do is get Xcode to say *"Summary Unavailable"* when my data formatter is copied to **/Developer/Library/Xcode/CustomDataViews/**

I created my bundle with the Xcode "bundle" template, and have put this into my C++ file:

```
#include "/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin/Contents/Headers/DataFormatterPlugin.h"
#include "Hi.h"

_pbxgdb_plugin_function_list *_pbxgdb_plugin_functions = NULL;

char * printHi( Hi * obj, int Id) {
    char * result = (char*)(_pbxgdb_plugin_functions->allocate(Id,100));
    sprintf( result, "%s", obj->string );
    return result;
}
```

Where the Hi object is trivial:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class Hi {
public:
    Hi( char * str ) {
        string = new char[strlen(str)+1];
        strcpy( string, str );
    }

    ~Hi() {
        delete( string );
    }

    void print( void ) {
        printf( "%s", string );
    }

    char * string;
};
```

I know my problem isn't with my .plist file because if I put the following in the StringSummary field, it will print out the **string** field;

```
%string%:s
```

However, if I put this in:  (Yes, I am linking this to a **Hi *** object, not a **Hi** object.)

```
{(char *)printHi($VAR, $ID)}:s
```

All I can get out is *Summary Unavailable*.  I'm debugging with a simple project:

```
#include "hi.h"

void foo( Hi * obj ) {
    obj->print();
}

int main( void ) {
    Hi h( "test!" );
    foo( &h );
    return 1;
}
```

Anybody got any tips for debugging debuggers?  :P

Comment: I would love to see an answer on this question!

Answer (score 1):

There is Product > Debug > Shared Libraries - you should check if your bundle is loaded at all.
Also it seems you can use any functions from currently running target - but _pbxgdb_plugin_function_list variable seems to be NULL at that point.